# USPS Web Tools Update

Tags: upgrade, usps, patches

We have got alert from USPS which is about upcoming updates:

> January 26 USPS Web Tools Update:  USPS Web Tools will be implementing
>   changes and additional features to the U.S. Postal Service APIs listed
>   below effective January 26, 2014 with testing available January 13th.

But I can't find official patch for Magento CE 1.7. Will new updates affect to our store, we only use Priority Mail and stamps.com integration. Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the release notes?

The Magento integration is using API's that are not technically affected, unless:

You ship any of the following: Live animals, Cremated remains, Hazardous materials

Other than that, it is just pricing updates.

Comment: Located at: https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/2014-january-webtools-release-notes.rtf